# Why won't R overplot a point on a horizontal boxplot, but will on a vertical boxplot?

Tags: r, plot, mean, boxplot

I have 2 boxplots on which I'd also like to include a point for the mean value.  It appears that, when you include horizontal=TRUE as an argument, the points() function no longer draws a point on the boxplot.

Here's my data:

```
fired <- c(34,37,37,38,41,42,43,44,44,45,45,45,46,48,49,53,53,54,54,55,56)
```

For Vertical boxplot:

```
> boxplot(fired,
+             main = "Fired Boxplot",
+             col=(c("gold")))
> points(mean(fired), lwd=5, col="darkred", pch=22)
```

[image: vertical boxplot with red square for mean]

But then for Horizontal boxplot (same data & functions with one argument change):

```
> boxplot(fired,
+             horizontal=TRUE,
+             main = "Fired Boxplot",
+             col=(c("gold")))
> points(mean(fired), lwd=5, col="darkred", pch=22)
```

No point:
  [image]

Why doesn't it plot the point in the horizontal=TRUE case?  It's just a value on an axis.

Comment: I also tried adding 'horizontal=TRUE' to point() in case there was some undocumented feature, but that's not the case:    "horizontal" is not a graphical parameter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works if you specify `y=1` in the `points` function.

```
boxplot(fired,
                    horizontal=TRUE,
                   main = "Fired Boxplot",
                   col=(c("gold")))
points(mean(fired),1, lwd=5, col="darkred", pch=22)
```

[image]

Comment: I knew it was something simple, but completely missed that in the documentation.  Thanks!